# Is there a way to convert xlsx to HTML using axlsx gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xls, xlsx, axlsx

I'm creating an xlsx file in rails app and I would like to be able to convert it to an HTML file or string. Excel offers this by clicking "File > Save As Web Page." Is there a way to do this using [axlsx gem](https://github.com/randym/axlsx)?

Comment: Yes: Parse it and throw it into a template of some kind. ERB? HAML? Your choice, but you've got a lot of work to do here. You will have to combine multiple gems here.

Comment: While you can, saying how in an answer is off-topic because it's too broad of a subject. We don't know your experience level, so a "detailed" answer would amount to a tutorial. Please read "[ask]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly axlsx doesn't convert for you out of the box: it is meant for reading and writing XLSX files. If you don't need to maintain all the markup you could use the [workbook](https://rubygems.org/gems/workbook) gem for this (in the background it uses gems like axlsx). You can open an Excel file and write it as HTML. It will use header tags to separate the different sheets.

(disclaimer: I'm the main author of the workbook gem)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

Axlsx is for generating files. It does not read xlsx files, and does not export different formats. You'll have to create a different output for your same data.